# Getting errorJavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid in MVC 3 using helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to implement JqGrid in MVC3 using helpers, but all the time i get a javascript error -**"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'".**I also add reference of MVCJqgrid in my project.
Here is my code for Jqgrid in view :-

```
@(Html.Grid(&quot;AgentGrid&quot;)
    .SetCaption(&quot;Agents&quot;)

    .AddColumn(new MvcJqGrid.Column(&quot;AgentId&quot;).SetLabel(&quot;Agent SSN&quot;))
        .AddColumn(new MvcJqGrid.Column(&quot;Name&quot;))
        .AddColumn(new MvcJqGrid.Column(&quot;Country&quot;))
        .AddColumn(new MvcJqGrid.Column(&quot;City&quot;))
        .AddColumn(new MvcJqGrid.Column(&quot;Title&quot;))
        .SetUrl(Url.Action(&quot;List&quot;, &quot;Home&quot;))
    .SetAutoWidth(true)
    .SetRowNum(10)
    .SetViewRecords(true)
    .SetPager(&quot;pager&quot;)
    )
```

and here is my code of action in controller:-

```
 public ActionResult List(GridSettings gridSettings)
        {
            DataContext db = new DataContext();

            string Name = string.Empty;
            string Country = string.Empty;
            string City = string.Empty;
            string Title = string.Empty;

            if (gridSettings.IsSearch)
            {
                Name = gridSettings.Where.rules.Any(r =&gt; r.field == "Name") ?
                       gridSettings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r =&gt; r.field == "Name").data : string.Empty;
                Country = gridSettings.Where.rules.Any(r =&gt; r.field == "Country") ?
                gridSettings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r =&gt; r.field == "Country").data : string.Empty;
                City = gridSettings.Where.rules.Any(r =&gt; r.field == "City") ?
               gridSettings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r =&gt; r.field == "City").data : string.Empty;
                Title = gridSettings.Where.rules.Any(r =&gt; r.field == "Title") ?
               gridSettings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r =&gt; r.field == "Title").data : string.Empty;

            }

            var Agents = db.Agent.ToList();
            int totalAgents = Agents.Count;
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalAgents / gridSettings.PageSize + 1,
                page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
                records = totalAgents,
                rows = (
                        from c in Agents
                        select new
                        {
                            id = c.AgentId,
                            cell = new[]
                    { c.AgentId.ToString(),
                        string.Format("{0} {1}", c.Name, c.Country),
                        c.City,
                        c.Title
                    }
                        }).ToArray()
            };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Please suggest me for resolve the issue !!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

According to error the scipts are not loaded properly, I presume this plugin does not add jqGrid library you need to add it manually in BundleConfig or in _Layout.chrtml depends of your structure.

**EDIT:** You need to put jqGrid init method in proper place(document.ready) also you need proper order of scripts for jqgrid. Read [this](https://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install&ei=SbYVUsDHLo7Kswan-YCQBQ&usg=AFQjCNF2jCBs1Zp_HLcMQipsbltvXXTsrw&sig2=BYG10gTTuoRcedEU9yzlUw&bvm=bv.51156542,d.Yms&cad=rja).

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({ blabla });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear that the `jqGrid object was not created`.

Please check you `include the jqGrid.js or min.js` file in the view

Use of firefox(firebug)/chrome and monitoring `console (press F12)` will help you to resolve this kind of problem